# Original domain in periodic triangulation with CGAL

Tags: cgal, triangulation

I have some questions regarding the periodic triangulation in CGAL.

1) According to my understanding of the manual examples (http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Periodic_2_triangulation_2/examples.html) and the *reference manual* if we don't use Iso_rectangle in constructing triangles, (0,0,1,1) is chosen as the default value, am I right?

2) What is the meaning of this statement from manual? "*input point is required to be an element of the half-open square representing the original domain*"

3) "*Another effect is that when the algorithm switches from 9-sheeted covering to 1-sheeted covering the Vertex_handles and Face_handles referencing deleted items becomes invalid*", Does this mean that If I have vertex circulator in code, those adjacent vertices that are in periodic boxes, are neglected and not displayed in the output?

Answer (score 0):

1) yes 
Triangulation_2 (const Iso_rectangle &domain=Iso_rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1), const Geom_traits &traits=Geom_traits())
http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Periodic_2_triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Periodic__2__triangulation__2.html#a1e9c60f7c9844a33edff96b95aeb6c85

2) all insert functions have a precondition ensuring that input points are in the half-open square defined in Secrtion 1 of the user manual
http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Periodic_2_triangulation_2/index.html#title0

3) I am not sure that I understand what you mean by "neglected". 
When the triangulation is in 1-sheeted covering mode, each vertex/face is stored only once, without copy, so the iterators/circulators simply traverse the triangulation directly in the flat torus. For a vertex circulator, you get all adjacent vertices.